# swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional runtime error

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a weird runtime error in swift. I have a CollectionViewController scene in the following order:

```
Items Controller Scene
    Items Controller (class: ItemsController)
        ItemCell (class: ItemCell, reuseIdentifier: "ItemCell")
            View...
```

And the classes:

```
class ItemCell : UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

}

class ItemsController : UICollectionViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            self.collectionView.registerClass(
                UICollectionViewCell.self,
                forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ItemCell");

        }

        override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }


        override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 10
        }

        override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(               "ItemCell",
            forIndexPath: indexPath) as ItemCell

            // ^^ The runtime error points to here

            cell.nameLabel.text = "Title";

            return cell
        }

}
```

This doesn't make any sense. What am I doing wrong? I have tried cleaning the project and recompiling but still didn't work (this generally works on most cases). I don't want to rewrite everything to work (that has happened to me also; recreating the Views fixed the problem). I am on Xcode 6.1; if there is no error here, I will pursue with recreating my storyboard but I don't want to do it until I am sure there is no problem in my code.

EDIT: Forgot to mention it. If I change the class from ItemCell to UICollectionViewCell in `collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` line, it at least runs. So, the problem does reside in the storyboard for assigning the custom class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found the problem. I forgot to change the class name to ItemCell when registering the class for the collection view:

```
self.collectionView.registerClass(ItemCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ItemCell")
```

EDIT: I don't have much experience with UICollectionViewController but I found out that, if I want to use the custom class using the above line will make all the IBOutlets nil. So removing that line fixes the problem.